Why does the rig change during record animation mode?
When I hit “Record Animation” in Play mode, my character changes to this setup:

Here’s what it looks like when Imported into the scene:

During play mode, the pre-baked animations (done in Blender) all work as expected. What causes the rig to change like this?
Edit: If I clear out the Animation Controller so that it's empty, this is the pose that the model defaults to. This is not the pose in Blender that I have set though. What would cause this?

could this be the first key frame of the first animation?

I've discovered that this is the default pose for a humanoid Rig in Unity. In other words, this does not appear to be a result of my setup.
I changed everything over to Generic in the model settings for the Rig and it retained the T-Pose.
